# ¿Cómo usar AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Se más o menos lo que es AJAX. Sin embargo, aún no me queda claro como utilizarlo, y me gustaría aprender a usarlo por que veo que es algo elemental a día de hoy.

He buscado tutoriales en Internet, pero en su mayoría están obsoletos y viejos. Mi pregunta es: ¿Podrían darme algún ejemplo de código sencillo que tengan y cómo aprender a usarlo? ¿Necesito un lenguaje de lado del servidor como PHP?

Comment: El tema me parece muy interesante, pero la pregunta cae en varios de los supuestos de [las preguntas que debemos evitar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), por ejemplo, ¿por qué te parecen obsoletos los tutoriales que has encontrado? En mi opinión, por su amplitud y la subjetividad de las opiniones que contiene, la pregunta debería ser puesta en espera. Me gustaría que pasaras a [meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/) y preguntaras como mejorar esta pregunta, porque es un buen tema y merece estar en Stackoverflow en español.

Comment: Pues básicamente solo deseo un código actual para podrr verlo. Nada del otro mundo.

Comment: Pues entonces busca en GitHub. Ahí hay más código: más de 23 mil repositorios, 53 millones de líneas de código, 25 mil wikis. Solo es cosa de querer buscar. [https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=ajax&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=ajax&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

Comment: Viene explicado? :)

Comment: Por supuesto :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Brevemente

AJAX es una técnica para realizar una solicitud a un recurso web. Por ejemplo, leer una página web.

Lo principal de AJAX es que se realiza de forma *asincrónica*. Y es *asincrónica* en términos de la carga global de la página, ya que permite hacer una solicitud una vez que la página ya fue obtenida, sin necesidad de recargarla.

#### Cuándo usarlo

- Actualizar la página sin necesidad de recargarla en el explorador.
- Solicitar datos al servidor (luego de que la página se haya cargado).
- Recibir datos de un servicio (luego de que la página se haya cargado).
- Enviar datos al servidor (en segundo plano).

Leyendo tu pregunta, me parece que ni siquiera sabés para qué usarlo aún... Bueno, primero creo que deberías pensar en qué dato querés obtener de la web cuando ya se cargó la página. Y esto sería, por ejemplo, cuando el usuario hace click en algún elemento, que busque más información de otro lado, o similar.

### Ejemplo de Código

```js
function solicitudAJAX(url){
    
    //Enviar con AJAX
    var http_request = false;

    //Crear el objeto
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //para IE6-
    else
        return false; //Error al crear el request

    //asignamos una función que se llamará (asincrónicamente) 
    //  cuando cambie el estado de la petición
    http_request.onreadystatechange = cambiaEstadoDelRequest;
    
    //hacemos el request
    http_request.open("GET", url, true);
    http_request.send(null);
    return true;
}

function cambiaEstadoDelRequest() {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) { // 4 significa que terminó
        if (http_request.status == 200) { //200 es la respuesta "OK" del server
            //acá leemos la respuesta (la página devuelta)
            var respuesta = http_request.responseText;
            
            //Acá el código que parsee a la respuesta <------
            
        } else {
            //El server tuvo otra respuesta (Por ej: 404 not found)
        }
    }

}
```

**Ejemplo de llamada:**

```js
solicitudAJAX("http://www.midominio.com/datos.html?buscar=algo");
```

---

> ¿Necesito un lenguaje de lado del servidor como PHP?

No. Necesitás definir qué querés hacer. Puede ser obtener una página generada con PHP, puede ser un HTML común, puede ser un WebService, puede ser cualquier recurso web que se te ocurra.

---

#### Más info: [MDN > AJAX > Primeros Pasos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/AJAX/Primeros_Pasos)

Comment: A menos que por AJAX te refieras a [esto](http://i.stack.imgur.com/004nj.png)

Comment: Yo incluiría también la novedosa fetch API : https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Lo principal de AJAX es que permite hacer peticiones a servidores sin recargar la página completa.
Las peticiones AJAX pueden ser asíncronas o no, y no tiene relación con el momento en que se hacen las peticiones.

Comment: @JoséM.Carnero Es asincrónico en términos de la carga global de la página (independientemente de si JS depende de la respuesta de un `async: false` que puede considerarse obsoleto). Es decir, asincrónico significa lo mismo que marcás como punto principal. No obstante, edité la respuesta para ponerlo más explícito.

Answer (score 6):

Tengo un ejemplo algo básico de AJAX. Debes usar PHP del lado del servidor y jQuery en el cliente (bootstrap para el diseño).

Inserta el código en tu servidor PHP y nombralo como "ajaxSleep.php", te devolverá las variables que le envíes por AJAX desde el cliente.

```
<?php
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
    $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
    sleep(4);//simulamos tiempo de espera de algunos segundos
    echo ("Tus datos: " . $nombre . " - " .     $apellido . " - " . $telefono);
?>
```

Este es el código que implementa AJAX de jQuery, nombralo como creas conveniente, y guardalo junto a "ajaxSleep.php":

```
<html>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p id="lblDatos">......</p>
            <button id="btnModal" class="btn btn-primary">Abrir modal</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal contenido-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <label for="txtNombre">Nombre: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNombre"/>

                        <label for="txtApellido">Apellido:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtApellido"/>

                        <label for="txtTelefono">Telefono:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTelefono"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">                            
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
                        <img src="img/cargandoPaginaWeb.gif" class="img-rounded" height="30px" width="30px" id="imgLoad" style="display:none">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--haca todos los script-->
    <!--Siempre debe ir jQuery primero q bootstrap-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#btnModal').click(function(event){
                clearModal();
                $('#myModal').modal('show');                
            }); 
            $('#btnGuardar').click(function(event){                    
                var n= $('#txtNombre').val();
                var a = $('#txtApellido').val();
                var t = $('#txtTelefono').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {"nombre" : n, "apellido" : a, "telefono" : t},
                    url: "ajaxSleep.php",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#imgLoad').show();
                    },
                    success: function(response) { 
                        $('#lblDatos').text(response);                           
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        //if(textStatus === 'timeout'){alert('Failed from timeout');}   
                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {alert('Not connect: Verify Network: ' + textStatus);}
                        else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {alert('Requested page not found [404]');} 
                        else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {alert('Internal Server Error [500].');}
                        else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');}
                        else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {alert('Time out error.');} 
                        else if (textStatus === 'abort') {alert('Ajax request aborted.');} 
                        else {alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);}
                    },
                    timeout: 5000
                    //timeout: 1000//para probar timeout
                }).always(function(){
                    $('#imgLoad').hide();
                    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');//Verificar uso 
                    clearModal();
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });  
            function clearModal(){
                //Limpio las cajas de texto del modal
                $('.modal-body input').val('');
            }    
        });            
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Recuerda agregar el .css de bootstrap 3 y los .js de bootstrap 3  y jQuery 3

Pega todo en un servidor PHP 5.6 o mayor. Los parámetros viajan desde el formulario hasta el servidor vía AJAX, y PHP se encarga de retornar los mismos valores.

Answer (score 6):

Por mantenernos un poco al día, desde que **ES6** llegó a nuestras vidas (aunque parece que muchos os resistís) tenemos disponible la API **fetch** para facilitarnos hacer llamadas AJAX.

#### Ejemplo

```
fetch('https://somedomine.com/some/url', {
    method: 'get'
}).then(response => {
  // Response :)
}).catch(err => {
  // Error :(
})
```

Os dejo algunos links interesantes:

- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Artículo de david Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)

Comment: Entre los que se resisten, es importante nombrar a: IE, Safari y Opera Mobile ([ver tabla de compatibilidad por navegador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Compatibilidad_del_navegador))

Comment: Es cierto que muchas de las nuevas *features* aún no son bien soportadas, pero para eso tenemos [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). También existen algunas librerías potentes como [SuperAgent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/)

Answer (score 0):

En **JQuery** tienes buen material para usar ajax:
https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/

JQuery es una magnifica libreria de funciones de javascript para los que somos vagos y vamos con prisa.

Comment: Quizás sería bueno agregar el código que muestre cómo realizar una solicitud genérica con jQuery

Comment: Tienes mucha info en la pagina del enlace, y en otras relacionadas, como ésta: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Aqui mismo tienes alguna info sobre jquery+ajax:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bajax%5d%20jquery

Comment: Lo recomendable creo que sería [edit] la respuesta agregando un ejemplo. Los enlaces pueden no estar disponibles, y el formato que seguimos es el de poner las respuestas acá (al menos con un ejemplo ilustrativo que puede ser complementado con un enlace)

Answer (score -3):

con Jquery, te envio un ejemplo que lo uso con mucha frecuencia para el tema de uso de ajax yo lo uso para extraer datos en formato Json.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

var config = {
    url: '../../aplicacion/crud/index.php',
    variables: 'tabla'
};
var fuentedata = sendData(config);
 function  sendData(config)
 {//json captura
 var json = null;
 $.ajax({
    'type': "POST",
    'data': config,
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': '' + config.url,
    'dataType': "json"
    , 'beforeSend': function (data)
    {
       // console.log('... cargando...');
    }
    , 'error': function (data) {
        //si hay un error mostramos un mensaje
        console.log('Tenemos problemas Houston ' + data);
    },
    'success': function (data) {
        json = data;
    }
    });
    return json;
}

});
```

Espero ser de ayuda.