# Busquedas sin recargar la pagina

Tags: java, javascript, html, sql, postgresql

Necesito realizar una búsqueda tipo facebook, es decir al escribir el nombre X en un input que se vaya filtrando de una consulta de base de datos sin recargar la pagina
Como debo hacerlo
Estoy trabajando con java y de base de datos postgresql

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Muéstranos tu código respectivo.

Comment: Suponiendo que desconoces **`Ajax`**, tu pregunta es un duplicado/relacionado de [¿Cómo usar AJAX?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax)

Comment: Pues no conozco nada de Ajax, pense que se podia hacer un llamado a algun metodo que yo tenga en java para que ejecute la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar un método que por cada vez que cambie el contenido del texto realice una llamada al `Service`, sería una buena idea utilizar un retardo de medio segundo para evitar demasiadas llamadas. Si estás utilizando JSF sería con `valueChangeListener`

Comment: En JSF el `valueChangeListener` no generará una llamada ajax, será un ciclo request/response común y corriente. En su lugar, desde JSF 2, lo que necesitas es ejecutar tu request con `<f:ajax>` y puedes escoger qué componentes enviar al servidor para disminuir la información que se envía, reduciendo así el ancho de banda.