# Cambiar contenido de la página sin actualizarla

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo una *Landing Page* dividida en dos columnas, la izquierda es el *NavBar* donde hay un acordeón con propiedades a la venta (es una web de una inmobiliaria) y a la derecha quiero que se haga un *display* de la información de la propiedad (imágenes, detalles de venta, botón de cotización etc...). Lo que quiero es que al hacer click en una propiedad del acordeón, la parte derecha se actualice con la información de la propiedad en cuestión. Ahora he de aclarar algo: La web tiene un **index.php** donde cada parte de la página es llamada con un `require` (el *NavBar*, el *body*, y el *footer* son integrados en el índice mediante la función `require` de *PHP*) algo así como *MVC* pero no tan complejo.

Ahora, el acordeón está en el *NavBar* gracias a un `require`, y las propiedades a su vez, están en el *NavBar* gracias a un `require` que las llama desde un archivo **propiedades.tpl**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen para que se ilustre parecida a la página.

```
<html>
    <body id="top">
        <?php require 'header.php'; ?>
        <!-- Main --> 
        <?php require 'body.html'; ?>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <?php require 'footer.html'; ?>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="accordion/js/jquery.accordion.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
            <script>

            $('.accordion').accordion({
                "transitionSpeed": 400,
                "singleOpen": false
            });         
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código del índice para que vean cómo está estructurada la página.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/scroll.css" />
    </head>
    <body id="top">
        <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
            <div class="inner">
                <a href="#" class="image avatar"><img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <h2>Bienvenido</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll">
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Apartamentos</strong></p>
                    <?php require 'aptos.tpl'; ?>
                </div>
                <div>
                <p><strong>Casas</strong></p>
                    <?php require 'casas.tpl'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código del *NavBar* para que vean (Sí, el *NavBar* se llama **header.php**)

Tenía pensado hacerlo con *AJAX* mediante `onClick=""`, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Quiero que al presionar una propiedad en el *NavBar* de la izquierda, luego se actualice la parte derecha de la página para que haga un *display* de la información de la propiedad.

Había pensado, en lugar de cargar toda una web diferente, almacenar la información de las propiedades en un array (archivo `.json` supongo) y que al hacer click, se lea esa información, y se reemplace en los campos pertinentes en la parte de información, pero no sé si eso funcionaría con imágenes. Además de que quiero hacer un deslizador con las imágenes de la propiedad, o una grilla de imágenes.

Comment: Quizás te sea útil leer: [¿Cómo usar AJAX?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21182/127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que utilizas JQuery, te doy algunas pistas:

- En el evento click del menú que corresponda deberías hacer una llamada ajax para recuperar la vista que quieres cargar a la derecha: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- Una vez que tienes el contenido lo añades al panel de la derecha: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Puesto todo junto podría queda algo así:

```
    $.ajax({
        url : "template1.htm",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $(".paneldecontenido").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Como es un código que vas a usar en varios elementos de menú te recomiendo que lo encapsules en un método.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Bien! funciona de maravilla, gracias Fernando!pero me gustaría que al hacer click en otra "propiedad" se haga una limpieza del anterior y se haga de nuevo el display, porque si no se iría amontonando todo.. Por cierto el codigo quedo asi: 
`function cargarDoc() {
 $.ajax({
        url : "footer.html",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $(".1").html(data);
        }
    });
}`

Comment: Va ya sta resulta que no se amontona, pues eso es todo, ya funciona, mil gracias hombre!

Comment: Hola @NicolasEcheverry! Si la respuesta solucionó tu pregunta por favor marcala como respuesta correcta así ayudamos a mejorar la comunidad. Saludos!

Comment: Nicolas, me alegro de que al final hayas resuelto el problema.