# ¿Cómo descargar archivo JSON con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero realizar una petición get para obtener un JSON y guardarlo en una variable de JavaScript. He encontrado el siguiente código pero no entiendo donde se guarda el contenido que tiene la URL.

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "url", false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: En el siguiente [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) conoceras como funciona el objecto `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo usar AJAX?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%c3%b3mo-usar-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta se guarda en `xmlhttp.responseText`, pero antes de manipular esa respuesta debes preguntar si el estado de la petición es 200 (petición exitosa), este estado se guarda en `xmlhttp.status`.

```
if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```