# Evitar redireccionamiento con JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tengo este js y esta consulta

```
    $("#sub").click( function(event) {

     $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
     $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
     function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 

        });
      });

      $('#myForm').submit(function() {
      return false;
      });
```

-procesarApuntarse.php

```
           <?php
         session_start();
        require_once "includes/config.php";

    $app = Aplicacion::getSingleton();
    $mysqli = $app->conexionBd();

     $id = $_POST['idOcio'];
     $rn = $_POST['idUser'];


        $sql = "INSERT INTO partecipantes (ID_Ocio, ID_Usuario, 
        Nombre_Publico)
                VALUES ('$id', '$rn', '1')";
       // $mysqli->query($sql) or die ($mysqli->error. " en la línea ". 
       (__LINE__));
    //header('Location: ../ocio.php');
    if($mysqli->query($sql)) echo "Successfully Inserted";
    else
      echo "Insertion Failed";
       ?>
```

Pero cada vez que inserto me redirige a procesarApuntarse.php, cuando yo lo que quiero es quedarme en la página donde he pulsado el botón. Dicha pagina es esta (la parte importante)
-sel_quedada.php

```
          <form id="myForm" action="codesincss/procesarApuntarse.php" 
        method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="idOcio" value='<?php echo "$id";?>'/> 
            <input type="hidden" name="idUser" value='<?php echo "$rn";?>'/> 
            <button id="sub" class='w3-button w3-dark- 
            blue'>Apuntarse</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax

Comment: como se haría??

Comment: Aqui hay ejemplos usando javascript y jquery: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax

Comment: Si te fijas en el codigo el OP ya esta utilizando ajax, el problema es que no esta previniendo el comportamiento por defecto del formulario. Lo que necesita es esto: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

Remueve el evento $("#sub").click() y sólo usa el evento submit

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Evita que la página actual vaya a la url del action
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serializeArray(), function(info) {
        $("#result").html(info); 
    });
});
```