# toggle checkbox con ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo una aplicacion web con mvc donde tengo un toggle button para cambiar el estado (activado/desactivado) pero no quiero recargar la pagina completa una vez se cambie el estado, tambien por alguna razon los datos que necesito de la vista para el controlador no pasan para poder actualizar el estado en la base de datos (activado/desactivado), ajax creo sea la respuesta pero estoy abierta a cualquier solucion. gracias

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-success float-right" href="@Url.Action("Create", 
"Season")">
<img src="~/icons/si-glyph-button-plus.svg" width="16" height="16" /> 
Agregar
</a>
<br />

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateStart)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateEnd)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateStart)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateEnd)
        </td>
        <td>


            <!--nnnnnnn-->
            <label class="tgl">
                <input type="checkbox" checked />
                <span class="tgl_body">
                    <span class="tgl_switch"></span>
                    <span class="tgl_track">
                        <span class="tgl_bgd"></span>
                        <span class="tgl_bgd tgl_bgd-negative"></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </label>

        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="@Url.Action("Edit","Season", new { id=item.Id})">
                    <img src="~/icons/si-glyph-edit.svg" width="16" height="16" /> Modificar
                </a>
                |
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="@Url.Action("Delete","Season", new { id=item.Id})">
                    <img src="~/icons/si-glyph-button-remove.svg" width="16" height="16" /> Eliminar
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

```
//aqui es donde habia estado probando hacerlo con jquery
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

[image: este es el UI que deseo lograr]

Comment: No veo ningun button en tu codigo

Comment: es el checkbox que esta haciendo de toggle

Comment: Entonces deberias de darle una clase o id, porque un checkbox no es un button y ese selector no te va a funionar.  Tampoco veo ningun p en tu codigo

Comment: el script es solo de prueba, lo inclui para si alguien me daba la idea de cambiar el checkbox por un button pues ya tenia el codigo, pero la idea del button no se acomoda al UI que tengo, por eso el checkbox toggle.

Comment: esta es el UI...

Comment: Ok, si le das a tu checkbox una clase, tu codigo deberia funcionar.  Ahora para  actualizar la base de datos vas a necesitar Ajax

Comment: eso es lo que estoy intentando, lograr actualizar la base de datos con ajax pero he intentado varios codigos y nada alguna idea?

Comment: actualice la pregunta con una imagen sobre el UI que deseo lograr

Comment: Tambien agrega el codigo Ajax que intentaste

Comment: Aqui hay varios ejemplos de Ajax usando javascript y jQuery: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax