# Mandar un array de JavaScript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, web

estoy iniciando en esto del JavaScript y PHP, tengo un problema que ya me está desesperando, el objetivo es enviar un array de JavaScript a un fichero para que este lo procese. Tengo el siguiente código en el body de mi HTML

```
<body>

    <table id="TblDestinos" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="FFFDC1">
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Direccion</th>
                <th>CP</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Destino 1</td>
                <td>Destino Dirección 1</td>
                <td>CP. Destino 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Destino 2</td>
                <td>Destino Dirección 2</td>
                <td>CP. Destino 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>



        <script>

            var Tabla = document.getElementById("TblDestinos");   
            var arrayTabla = [];
            var arrayFila = [];

            for (var i = 1; i < Tabla.rows.length; i++)
            {

                arrayFila = [];
                CeldasDeFila = Tabla.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

                var Dest_Nomb = CeldasDeFila[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                var Dest_Dir = CeldasDeFila[1].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                var Dest_CP = CeldasDeFila[2].innerHTML.toLowerCase();

                arrayFila.push(Dest_Nomb);
                arrayFila.push(Dest_Dir);
                arrayFila.push(Dest_CP);

                arrayTabla.push(arrayFila);

            }


function toObject(array) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    rv[i] = array[i];
  return rv;
}

var obj = toObject(arrayTabla);
var MiJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

 //Como envío MiJSON a PHP? y como recupero el array en PHP?

    </script>


</body>
```

Ojalá me puedan ayudar, me quedó en la parte donde convierto el array a objeto y de ahí ya no sé como enviarlo a un fichero PHP, y como recibirlo en PHP y convertirlo a array nuevamente.

De antemano muchas gracias a todos. Ya investigué pero no entiendo muy bien los ejemplos.

P.D. Uso Windows 7, PHP 7.

Mil gracias.

Comment: Tienes que usar Ajax.  Aqui te explican como: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Debes enviar tus datos de la siguiente manera:

```js
var Tabla = document.getElementById("TblDestinos");   

var destinos = new Array();
var direcciones = new Array();
var codigospostales = new Array();

for (var i = 1; i < Tabla.rows.length; i++)
{

  CeldasDeFila = Tabla.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

  var Dest_Nomb = CeldasDeFila[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
  var Dest_Dir = CeldasDeFila[1].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
  var Dest_CP = CeldasDeFila[2].innerHTML.toLowerCase();

  destinos.push(Dest_Nomb);
  direcciones.push(Dest_Dir);
  codigospostales.push(Dest_CP);

}

var datos = new Object();

datos.destinos = destinos;
datos.direcciones = direcciones;
datos.codigospostales = codigospostales;

// Enviar por ajax la variable datos
console.log(datos);

/*

Para recibirlos por php recorres el array enviado

$destinos = $_POST['destinos'];
$direcciones = $_POST['direcciones'];
$codigospostales = $_POST['codigospostales'];

foreach ($direcciones as $key => $value) {
  $direccion = $value;
  $destino = $destinos[$key];
  $codigopostal = $codigospostales[$key];

  echo $direccion.", ".$destino.", ".$codigopostal;
}

*/
```

```html
<table id="TblDestinos" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="FFFDC1">
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Direccion</th>
      <th>CP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Destino 1</td>
      <td>Destino Dirección 1</td>
      <td>CP. Destino 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Destino 2</td>
      <td>Destino Dirección 2</td>
      <td>CP. Destino 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Ya entiendo, oye y cómo lo mando por ajax? ando muy atrasado en eso, me podrías poner un ejemplo.

Comment: Aquí te envío el ejemplo hecho... recueda incluir la librería JQuery en tu documento html 
https://codepen.io/diegoJS20/pen/KeRNdy

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó a la perfección, solo me queda una úlitima duda, como uno los tres array en uno solo bidimensional? es que en mi PHP hice una funcion que va a trabajar con un array bidimensioanal. Ojalá me puedas ayudar, muchas gracias,