# como agregar a carrito drecto desde datatables y php?buen di

Tags: php, html, json, bootstrap, botón

Buen dia
mi problema es que no se como agregar un producto directamente a mi tabla detallesCarrito desde datatables. 
tengo en las dos ultimas columnas un input donde tiene de fondo la cantidad de existencias para escribir las que quiere agregar a carrito y al lado el boton AGREGAR A CARRITO.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
 while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_array())
 {     
  $row = array();
  
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
  {
   
   if ( $aColumnas[$i] == "version" )
   {    
    /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
    $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];
   }
   else if ( $aColumnas[$i] != ' ' )
   {
    /* General output */
    if($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]==$aRow['imag1']){//si la columna es imagen, imprime la imagen, sino los datos
     $row[]= "<td><a href='detalles_productoDistr.php?ID=".$aRow['idProd']."'><img src=".$aRow['imag1']." width=70 heigth=70 ></a></td>";
    }else 
    {
     if($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]==$aRow['precioMay']){
      $row[] ='$'. $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];//imprime el '$'  si es precio
     }else{
      if($aRow[$aColumnas[$i]]==$aRow['existProd'])
      {
       $row[] = "<input type='text' name='agregarCarrito' id='textfield7' placeholder=".'Maximo:'.$aRow['existProd']." style='width: 80px' >";

      #

      }else{
       $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i]];
      }
     }
    }           
   }
  }
  $row[]="<button name='agregar'  type='submit' class='btn btn-large btn-primary'  value='AGREGAR A CARRITO' >Agregar a Carrito<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span></button>";
   
  $output['aaData'][] = $row;      
 }

 echo json_encode( $output );
```

QUIERO CAMBIAR EL IMPUT POR:

```
  <select class="selectpicker">
```

DONDE escriba o seleccione hasta la cantidad maxima que se pueda.
y el BOTON si agrege a carrito. Esto no se si pueda llamando a una funcion desde el boton, y no se si se pueda hacer eso.
No se si pido cosas faciles o dificiles, mas mi mente se cerro y no se como hacerle, ya le busque de muchas formas.

Comment: Como piensas agregar al carrito, tienes alguna funcion que hay que llamar, o vas a guardar la informacion en una tabla de la base de datos?

Comment: Quiero guardar la información en una tabla de datos

Comment: Entonces tienes que mandar la informacion al servidor.  Puedes hacerlo via Ajax.

Comment: No tengo conocimiento de Ajax, sería por función?? O como le hago. Donde puedo ver un ejemplo?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax

Comment: tendras un ejemplo que se acerque a lo que busco