# Ejecutar consulta MySQL en onChange

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tengo un `select` que muestra los departamentos:

```
<select name="dpto" id="dpto">
   <option value="3">ATLANTICO</option>
   <option value="12">CESAR</option>
</select>
```

Lo que necesito es que al momento de seleccionar X departamento haga una consulta a la Base de Datos y me muestre los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
<span class="tipoboletin">Tipo Boletin: <b><?php echo $B_Tipo_Boletin ?></b></span>
```

Esta es la consulta MySQL que tengo:

```
SELECT * FROM boletin WHERE Departamento = '" . $idDpto . "'"
```

Donde `$idDpto` seria el `value` del departamento que seleccione.

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax.

Comment: Y los datos se verian instantaneamente? Osea sin necesidad de recargar la pagina? Que cada vez que seleccione un departamento se muestren los datos?

Comment: Si, eso es exactamente para lo que sirve Ajax.

Comment: Me podrias ayudar y/o explicar como hacerlo, te lo agradeceria.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax

Comment: como ya dijeron antes, con ajax y jquery puede hacer eso,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera esto es solo un ejemplo hay muchas formas de hacerlo estas es una de la mas facil ejemplo:

```
  <select name="dpto" id="dpto">
       <option value="3">ATLANTICO</option>
       <option value="12">CESAR</option>
    </select>


   <div id="resultados"></div><!--aqui se mostraran los resultados-->
```

**archivo js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

           $("#dpto").on("change",function(){

            var valorSelect=$(this).val()//obtenemos el valor seleccionado en una variable


        $.ajax({

            url:"callback.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{ valorSelect:valorSelect},//enviamos lo seleccionado

            success:function(respuesta){
               console.log( respuesta)
             $("#resultados").html(respuesta);//en el div con el id respuestas mostramos los resultados del callback

            }

          })

          })

        })
```

**callback.php**

```
$valorSelect=$_POST["valorSelect"];//recojemos lo seleccionado

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM boletin WHERE Departamento = '" . $valorSelect . "'");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

echo...////aqui imprimes tu resultados para que ajax lo recoja
```

espero que sea de tu ayuda saludos!

Comment: No me funciono.

Comment: pon el codigo que hiciste completo a ver que pasa y el error que te muestra

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#dpto").on("change",function(){
                var idDpto = $(this).val();
                alert(idDpto);
                $.ajax({
                    url:"ConsultasMySQL.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{ idDpto: idDpto},
                    success:function(respuesta){
                        $("#resultados").html(respuesta);
                    }
                });
            });
        });`

Comment: Y en el PHP tengo esto:
`$idDpto = $_POST["idDpto"];
echo "Id Dpto: " . $idDpto;`

Comment: El `value` del `select` lo pasa perfectamente, lo que no funciono fue la consulta, osea no se muestran los cambios reflejados.

Comment: y el error que te muestra?

Comment: el codigo php podrias mostrarlo para ayudarte a solucionarlo

Comment: Este es codigo php:
`$idDpto = $_POST["idDpto"];
echo "Id Dpto: " . $idDpto;
$sql_Boletin = "SELECT * FROM consultaanticorrupcion.boletin WHERE Numero = '" . $Numero . "' AND Departamento = '" . $idDpto . "'";
$result_Boletin = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_Boletin);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result_Boletin)) {
    $B_Hora = $rows[1];
    $B_Fecha = $rows[2];
    $B_Numero = $rows[3];
}`

Comment: necetito el archivo completo del php donde esta la conexion a la base de datos  y de donde sale la variable $Numero?

Comment: Dame un correo donde enviartelo.

Comment: andygibbs700@gmail.com

Comment: Ya te lo envie. Espero puedas ayudarme. De ante mano, mil gracias!

Comment: ok  dame unos minutos estoy saliendo de el work XD!