# ¿Cómo lograr que esta petición AJAX retorne algún valor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

No funciona el JSON que envío por ajax, no me devuelve ningún valor el API. ¿Podrian ayudarme por favor?

```
alert(resp);
                var key=resp;
                var merchanidtest="515776502";
                var amount=$('input[name=amount]').val();
                var ipcliente="190.117.255.189";
                var SendInfo='{'
                               +'"amount":'+amount+','
                               +'"antifraud":{'               
                                  +'"clienteIp":"'+ipcliente+'",'
                                  +'"merchanDefineData":{'
                                                     +'"MDD1":"web",'
                                                     +'"MDD2":"can1",'
                                                     +'"MDD3":"can2"}},'
                                       +'"channel":"web",'      
                                       +'"recurrenceMaxAmount",1000.00}';
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "post",
                                dataType: 'json',
                                           url:"https://apitestenv.vnforapps.com/api.ecommerce/v2/ecommerce/token/session/"+merchanidtest,
                                 async: true,
                                 cache: false,
                                 headers: {
                                         Authorization: resp,
                                         contentType: "application/json"

                                              },
                                           data:JSON.stringify(SendInfo),

                                           success: function(resp){

                                                 alert(resp.sessionKey);

                                                 alert(resp.expirationTime);

                                                    }
                                                });
```

Comment: `SendInfo` deberia ser un objeto y no un string.

Comment: tendras un ejemplo amigo

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax/21210#21210

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer dos cosas, primera cambiar ese `JSON.stringify` por `JSON.parse`.

La segunda lo puedes hacer de este modo, que te resultara mas fácil

```
alert(resp);
var key = resp;
var merchanidtest = "515776502";
var amount = $('input[name=amount]').val();
var ipcliente = "190.117.255.189";
var SendInfo = {
  "amount": amount,
  "antifraud": {
  "clienteIp": ipcliente,
  "merchanDefineData": {
  "MDD1": "web",
  "MDD2": "can1",
  "MDD3": "can2"}},
  "channel": "web",
  "recurrenceMaxAmount":"1000.00"};
$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "https://apitestenv.vnforapps.com/api.ecommerce/v2/ecommerce/token/session/" + merchanidtest,
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      headers: {
        Authorization: resp,
        contentType: "application/json"

      },
      data: SendInfo,

      success: function (resp) {

        alert(resp.sessionKey);

        alert(resp.expirationTime);

      }
```