# Como poner un span dentro de un input y que lo tome como valor para guardar en la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, base-de-datos

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Coberturas</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Marcar/Desmarcar Todos</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" onclick="marcar(this);" class="form-control m-b"></div>

                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Continuacion de Viaje</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas1" value="ROT (Volcadura) 10% Riesgos ordinarios de transito 5% Robo total 20% Huelgas y alborotos populares 5%" class="form-control m-b" checked></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">No Continuacion de Viaje</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas2"  value="Riesgos ordinarios de transito (Cobertura Basica) 5% Robo total con violencia y/o asalto 20% Robo parcial con violencia y/o asalto 20% Rapiña, arteria, pillaje y hurto a consecuencia de un riesgo ordinario de transito20% Mojadura y Oxidacion 5%" class="form-control m-b noCont"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas3" value="Contaminacion y Manchas por contacto con otras cargas 5% Rotura y Rajadura 5% Merma 5% Derrame 5% Bodega a bodega 5% Maniobras a bodega 5% Fallas en el sistema de refrigeracion y calefaccion 5%" class="form-control m-b noCont"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas4"  value="Maniobras de carga y descarga 5% Estadia en recintos fiscales y fiscalizados por 30 dias 5% Barredura 5% Echazon 5% Barateria del capitan y la tripulacion 5% Huelgas y alborotos populares 5% ROT (Volcadura) 10%" class="form-control m-b noCont"></div>
                                </div>
```

Necesito mover el texto de varios `span` para que conformen el `value` de los `input` que los preceden. Además necesito poder operar con los mismos, tal y como se muestra en el código. Tengo unas funciones creadas que se encargan de las operaciones matemáticas pero los `input` están vacíos.

```html
<form id="nclientes" name="nclientes" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe Asegurado</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular();" name="importe" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div id="span.derecha"class="form-group">
                                   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cuota Base (%)</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor2" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular();"  name="cuota" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Prima Neta</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="prima" class="form-control m-b"><span id="result" type="text" name="prima"></span></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">IVA (16%)</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="iva" class="form-control m-b"><span id="resultado3" type="text" name="iva"></span><br></div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="total" class="form-control m-b"><span id="total" type="text" name="total"></span></div>
                                </div>
                                                                
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-5">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Generar certificado</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**Con la ayuda de un usuario he llegado hasta este script que adjunto en imagen**

El script no funciona como necesito, pero no veo el fallo en el mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Si ya tienes el valor en el input por qué quieres guardarlo en un span? No termina de entenderse bien lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax.

Comment: Tienes el código para guardarlo en la base de datos? Si es así ponlo en tu pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: @Kiko_L no lo tengo en el input, lo tengo en el span, eso es lo que quiero que me lo muestre en el input y me permita guardarlo

Comment: @alanfcm en vez de script usar Ajax? como?

Comment: Te vale un script jQuery? o debe ser si o si javascript?

Comment: @Emerita ya agrege el codigo en la pregunta

Comment: @Emerita lo que sea pero que funcione y lo guarde xD jaja

Comment: ok, te monto un pequeño script en jquery para que te pase el valor a los inputs de manera automática.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax/21210#21210

Comment: @Emerita Muy bien

Comment: te sirve tener los datos al interno de los `span` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para solucionar tu problema, lo que haria es agregar un `id` a tus `input`, ya que los datos al interno del `span` los estas agregando desde JS.

eso quiere decir que los podes agregar directamente a tus inputs tambien, si te sirve mostrar los resultados al lado del input, deja los `span` si no simplemente asignale un `id` a tu input y inserta los datos directamente ahí.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        valor=$(this).next('span').text();
        $(this).val(valor);
    })
});

function formatear(dato) {
  return dato.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
    });
}

 function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');
  var resultado3 = document.getElementById('resultado3');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*valor2/100;
  var iva = parseInt(valor)*valor2*1.16/100;
  var t = iva - descuento;
    
  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = 'Prima: ' + formatear(descuento.toFixed(2));
  total.innerHTML = 'Total: ' + formatear(iva.toFixed(2));
  resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + formatear(t.toFixed(2));
  $("#result-input").val(formatear(descuento.toFixed(2)));
  $("#resultado3-input").val(formatear(t.toFixed(2)));
  $("#total-input").val(formatear(iva.toFixed(2)))
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>asd</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 
 <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe Asegurado</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular()" name="importe" class="form-control m-b" ></div>
</div>

<div id="span.derecha"class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cuota Base (%)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input id="valor2" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular()"  name="cuota" class="form-control m-b">
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Prima Neta</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" id="result-input" name="prima" class="form-control m-b">
        <span id="result" type="text" name="prima">7</span>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">IVA (16%)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" id="resultado3-input" name="iva" class="form-control m-b">
        <span id="resultado3" type="text" name="iva">5</span>
        <br>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" id="total-input"name="total" class="form-control m-b">
        <span id="total" type="text" name="total">3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**desarrollo tomado de la respuesta de Emerita**

espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Me parece maravilloso como copias mi desarrollo sin decir que lo has cogido de mi respuesta al menos, no?.

Comment: @Emerita no sabia que era tu desarrollo, el script lo saque de la foto del scritpt que habia agregado a la pregunta

Comment: Pues solo había una respuesta a la pregunta. Toma por costumbre, y no porque me moleste que cojas el código o no, leer las respuestas.

Comment: @Emerita lei la respuesta, y vi que no habia diferencias en el codigo, pero repito no sabia que era todo parte de tu desarrollo, pense que era parte de la pregunta ya que el codigo aparecia ahi, ahora meto la referencia

Comment: No necesito que pongas referencia, la respuesta válida es la tuya. Has agregado más código. Lo que no entiendo es como no viste que la imagen era mi respuesta xD. Me da lugar a pensar que solo soltaste tu desarrollo y ea, a correr.

Comment: Por que el $(document).ready(function(){  ya no me deja agregar mis checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>asd</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 
 <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe Asegurado</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular()" name="importe" class="form-control m-b"></div>
</div>

<div id="span.derecha"class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cuota Base (%)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input id="valor2" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular()"  name="cuota" class="form-control m-b">
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Prima Neta</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" name="prima" class="form-control m-b">
        <span id="result" type="text" name="prima">7</span>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">IVA (16%)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" name="iva" class="form-control m-b">
        <span id="resultado3" type="text" name="iva">5</span>
        <br>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" name="total" class="form-control m-b">
        <span id="total" type="text" name="total">3</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

$('input').each(function(){
    valor=$(this).next('span').text();
    $(this).val(valor);
})
   
});
function formatear(dato) {
  return dato.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
});
}
 function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');
  var resultado3 = document.getElementById('resultado3');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*valor2/100;
  var iva = parseInt(valor)*valor2*1.16/100;
  var t = iva - descuento;
    
  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = 'Prima: ' + formatear(descuento.toFixed(2));
  total.innerHTML = 'Total: ' + formatear(iva.toFixed(2));
  resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + formatear(t.toFixed(2));
}
</script>
```

He modificado mi código para que quede funcionando con lo que solicitas. Pruebalo y dime, con respecto a este código, que te falla o necesitas.

Por cierto, en los formularios, el method debe ir con mayusculas. Esto es que `method="post"` debe ser `method="POST"`. Prueba a modificar el valor de los inputs, que los coge de los span puesto por mi y me dices si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: cheque el link que agregaste y no se si por que falte el importe no me muestre los resultados automaticamente? y al parecer no me hace nada

Comment: Los inputs me aparecen con el valor asd, salvo el primero que no tiene span. A ti no?

Comment: Si pero al momento que yo pongo el importe y la cuota que no tienen span me daba en automatico el valor, no se puede asi?

Comment: De todas formas, ten en cuenta que yo aquí no estoy llamando a la función calcular que tienes tu. Yo solo pongo los importes. En mi ejemplo lo unico que hacer es pasar el valor a los inputs. Si tu función calcular se ejecuta despues que lo mio te debe hacer la operación.

Comment: y se podra meter ese script de calcular a tu script?

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta con lo nuevo. No te pongo el jsfiddle porque no funciona ahí. Pega tal cual el código en tu proyecto y debería funcionar.

Comment: modifique el scrip con el tuyo y me sale igual :/ me los pone abajo

Comment: Ok modiico mi pregunta con el codigo hasta el momento y ya me dices si estoy mal en algo..

Comment: Editado. Mira a ver si tira.

Comment: Solo me pone el valor que le diste a los span 7, 5 y 3 y el resultado me lo sigue dando abajo de los inputs

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92255/discussion-between-emerita-and-isaias-alejandro-sanchez).