# ¿Cómo hacer que Ajax funcione correctamente?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un código con el que calculo talla de zapatos en diferentes países, hasta ahí todo bien.
Sucede que cada que el usuario busca su talla la pagina se actualiza. Estoy usando `Ajax` y `Jquery` para evitar esto, pero no se si mi código esta escrito de la forma correcta pues no funciona. 
¿Podrían darme una mano?

Muchas gracias desde ya.

Acá mi código:

(Formulario para ingresar la talla)

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="javascript:calcular()" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="nuevo"><select class="form-control" name="from" id="from"><option value="undefined">Medida inicial</option><option value="Col" id="Col">Col</option><option value="Us" id="US">US</option><option value="EU" id="EU">EU</option><option value="UK" id="UK">UK</option><option value="Cm" id="Cm">Cm</option></select>
  <div
    class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="talla_recibida" id="talla_recibida" placeholder="Insertar talla"></div>
  <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Convertir   </button></div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col</th>
                <th>US</th>
                <th>UK</th>
                <th>EU</th>
                <th>Cm</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_col ?></td>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_us ?></td>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_uk ?></td>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_eu ?></td>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_cm ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

(script de la función `ajax`)

```
<script> 
  function calcular() /* La funcion envia los datos del formulario 
 al php "calcular.php" */
  {
    var from = document.getElementById("from").value
    var talla_recibida = document.getElementById("talla_recibida").value
    var url = "calcular.php";

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        data:{ from: from, talla_recibida: talla_recibida},
    })
  }
</script>
```

(`calcular.php` - Los códigos que convierten la talla están incluidos y las variables `$talla_col`, `$talla_US`, etc. Vienen de ahí)

```
<?php


$from = $_POST['from'];
$talla_recibida = $_POST['talla_recibida'];


include 'from_us.php';
include 'from_eu.php';
include 'from_uk.php';
include 'from_col.php';
include 'from_cm.php';



echo $talla_col;  
echo $talla_us;
echo $talla_uk;
echo $talla_eu;
echo $talla_cm;


?>
```

Comment: Estás enviando la petición `AJAX` pero no estás haciendo nada cuando recibes la respuesta. Debes añadir un `callback` y realizar alguna acción (dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer) cuando recibas los datos.

Comment: Hola ElChiniNet, gracias por tu comentario. Disculpa mi falta de conocimiento en esto. Pensé que incluyendo el archivo calcular.php dentro del index y llamando las variables de los resultados podría funcionar. Te molestaría hablarme mas acerca del callback?

Comment: Intenta echarle una ojeada a [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%c3%b3mo-usar-ajax). Si no puedes hacer nada con él me avisas e intento redactar una respuesta más específica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema en cada uno de los códigos que me pasas, lo resuelvo y te lo explico puntualmente.

Empezando por el `HTML`, para enviar el formulario necesitas evitar que se redireccione el formulario cuando le des click al botón y en vez de eso ejecute el `ajax`por lo tanto el botón no debe ser de tipo `submit` ya que este botón envía automáticamente el formulario, por lo tanto hay varías formas de solucionar esto, pero la que te dejo es más simple y es cambiarlo de tipo `submit` a `button` así:

```
<div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calcular()" type="button">Convertir   </button></div>
```

Por lo tanto el `HTML` queda así:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="nuevo"><select class="form-control" name="from" id="from"><option value="undefined">Medida inicial</option><option value="Col" id="Col">Col</option><option value="Us" id="US">US</option><option value="EU" id="EU">EU</option><option value="UK" id="UK">UK</option><option value="Cm" id="Cm">Cm</option></select>
  <div
    class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="talla_recibida" id="talla_recibida" placeholder="Insertar talla"></div>
  <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calcular()" type="button">Convertir   </button></div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col</th>
                <th>US</th>
                <th>UK</th>
                <th>EU</th>
                <th>Cm</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_col ?></td>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_us ?></td>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_uk ?></td>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_eu ?></td>
                <td><?php include 'calcular.php'; echo $talla_cm ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Segundo es que la función de `ajax` no estás pidiendo una respuesta devuelta sino que simplemente haga la petición y finalice, por lo tanto esto se puede cambiar usando `success:` que se ejecuta cuando la petición fue exitosa, quedaría así:

```
<script> 
  function calcular() /* La funcion envia los datos del formulario 
 al php "calcular.php" */
  {
    var from = document.getElementById("from").value
    var talla_recibida = document.getElementById("talla_recibida").value
    var url = "calcular.php";

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        data:{ from: from, talla_recibida: talla_recibida},
        success: function(response){
          console.log(response)//Response es la respuesta que te llega de la petición puede llamarse de cualquier forma
        }
    })
  }
</script>
```

Y por ultimo `PHP`, `Ajax` cuando hace una petición su respuesta siempre es un texto plano, por lo tanto, el devuelve todo lo que se imprime en el archivo php en texto plano, en este caso sí quieres devolver variables deberías una `json_encode` y devolverlas en formato `json`, pero pues como no sé sí en ese contexto lo necesitas, entonces lo dejo así, ahí estaría funcionando el `ajax`.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Para hacer lo que te digo puedes devolver una variable de tipo JSON de la siguiente forma:

`PHP`

```
<?php
  $from = $_POST['from'];
  $talla_recibida = $_POST['talla_recibida'];


  include 'from_us.php';
  include 'from_eu.php';
  include 'from_uk.php';
  include 'from_col.php';
  include 'from_cm.php';



  $response["talla_col"] = $talla_col;  
  $response["talla_us"] = $talla_us;
  $response["talla_uk"] = $talla_uk;
  $response["talla_eu"] = $talla_eu;
  $response["talla_cm"] = $talla_cm;

  echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Y en el método `AJAX` tienes que hacer que el detecte y devuelva esa variable como json y no como texto plano de esta manera:

```
<script> 
  function calcular() /* La funcion envia los datos del formulario 
 al php "calcular.php" */
  {
    var from = document.getElementById("from").value
    var talla_recibida = document.getElementById("talla_recibida").value
    var url = "calcular.php";

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data:{ from: from, talla_recibida: talla_recibida},
        success: function(response){
          var html = "<td>"+ response["talla_col"]+"</td>"
          + "<td>"+ response["talla_us"]+"</td>"
          + "<td>"+ response["talla_uk"]+"</td>"
          + "<td>"+ response["talla_eu"]+"</td>"
          + "<td>"+ response["talla_cm"]+"</td>";
          $("tbody tr").html(html);
        }
    })
  }
</script>
```

Algo así podría ser, por lo tanto el `HTML` queda así:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="nuevo"><select class="form-control" name="from" id="from"><option value="undefined">Medida inicial</option><option value="Col" id="Col">Col</option><option value="Us" id="US">US</option><option value="EU" id="EU">EU</option><option value="UK" id="UK">UK</option><option value="Cm" id="Cm">Cm</option></select>
  <div
    class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="talla_recibida" id="talla_recibida" placeholder="Insertar talla"></div>
  <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calcular()" type="button">Convertir   </button></div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col</th>
                <th>US</th>
                <th>UK</th>
                <th>EU</th>
                <th>Cm</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Alguna duda o sugerencia la comentas y espero te sirva, saludos!!

Comment: Hola DaxTter77, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido mucho. Estoy haciendo la parte del Json para devolver las variables como tu lo dices. Necesito que los resultados se impriman en la tabla de mi html. ya tengo el json y edité el succes del Ajax de la siguiente manera.

success: function(calculo){
          
                   document.getElementById("col").innerHTML = calculo; 
        } 
Lo que hace que todos los indices de mi json se impriman en el <td> con el id "col" (puse un id a cada td).   lo que quiero es que cada indice se imprima en su <td> correspondiente.

Comment: @EstebanAcosta, puedes hacer algo como esto: https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/vyu2b841/ imagina que `json` son los datos que te llegan del servidor, y que en callback ejecutas el `each` en cada fila.

Comment: @EstebanAcosta ya te agrego el ejemplo a ver como te podría quedar.

Comment: Muchas gracias DaxTter77, he seguido tus instrucciones y ha funcionado. Solo tuve que agregar un id al <tbody> de mi html y declararlo en el Ajax para que los resultados se imprimieran ahí y agregar el signo pesos a las variables con que hiciste el json (aunque no se si influya en realidad) y listo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti también  ElChiniNet. También estuve mirando tu código, pero soy muy nuevo en esto y me incliné por la otra respuesta. Se me facilitó mas. Pero muchas gracias por el apoyo

Comment: @EstebanAcosta es verda, los cambios que hiciste están bien, es un despiste que me da aveces y ya lo modifiqué en la respuesta, me alegro que lo hayas hecho, suerte con el proyecto.