# ¿Como añadir el valor del timestamp de Javascript a una variable de php?

Tags: php, javascript, timestamp

tengo una duda. Estoy tratando de hacer un **Time left**. Lo he intentado con Javascript y su TimeStamp y todo va bien, pero eso no pasa no lo mismo con PHP. No quiero pedir mucho, solo me gustaría saber como puedo añadir la función *Date.now();* de Javascript como valor de una variable a php (Solo el valor del timestamp de JavaScript, ya que PHP y Javascript no comparten el mismo Timestamp).

Comment: Podrías usar Ajax para mandar el dato del cliente (JavaScript) al servidor (PHP).

Comment: Y como lo hago?

Comment: Si lo divides entre mil, la parte entera es el marca de tiempo de PHP. Cabe notar que la fecha/hora del navegador no es del todo confiable.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que la variable $tiempo tenga el valor de Date.now(); en lo que es en Javascript. Ya que Date.now(); de javascript es diferente al time() de PHP

Comment: [Revisa esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21182/29967)  u otras que explican cómo funciona Ajax. Luego intenta tu código y si tienes problemas con él te ayudaremos. Hace falta un punto de partida concreto para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias!