# ¿Como validar un campo en laravel con un condicional?

Tags: php, laravel, validación, relaciones

¿Cómo mandar un mensaje de error de validación cuando uso un condicional?
Por ejemplo:

```
$months = $economic_activity->taxreturns()->whereDate('month_declare', $validated['month_declare'])->get();
```

//$months devuelve un array

```
    if(count($months) > 0){
      //Muestra mensaje de error de validación en el campo "month_declare"
    }else{
      //continúa el código normalmente
    }
```

Lo que necesito es que si entra en la condición, mande un mensaje de validación fallida en cierto campo de la vista. Lo hago de esta forma ya que los métodos existentes de validación no se adaptan a lo que necesito debido a que tengo que comparar el campo **month_declare** con la relación de otro modelo

Comment: Para mostrar un mensaje desde el BackEnd hay muchas maneras. Pero te aconsejo manejarlo con JavaScript, usar algún framework en el front y poder manejar los errores que el back retorne desde allí.

Comment: Podes usar una función anónima donde poner esa lógica https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para retornar un mensaje de validación debes lanzar una excepción de `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException` documentación: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.html

Ejemplo:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;


throw ValidationException::withMessages(['campo_1' => 'mensaje1', 'otro_campo' => 'mensaje2']):
```

Comment: Era justamente lo que necesitaba. Muchísimas gracias. De esta manera puedo devolver un error tal cual como en la validación. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer la validación dentro de una función, a la cual le pases como parámetro la variable $months y devuelves el resultado del condicional

```
function validaMes ($month)
{
   if(count($months) > 0){
       $resultado = "Hay un error";
    }else{
       $resultado = "OK";
    }
   return $resultado
}
```

Comment: si, entiendo eso. El detalle sería como hacer que me tome esa función como parte de la validación para que me pueda devolver los mensajes de error

Comment: Mostrar mensajes de error desde el servidor es viable pero no recomendable, mas aún utilizando frameworks de BackEnd. Te aconsejo tomar los errores con una petición AJAX (por ejemplo) y mostrar el error desde JS en el campo de la vista que desees. [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21182/c%C3%B3mo-usar-ajax)